# Enumerate (give a name) the records of a cross join of two or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations, combinatorics

I need to give a unique identifier to any single row resulting from a cross join (cross products) of two tables (two sets) with SQL Server. Basically i need to "condense" the columns values of any row of the result set in a unique identifier. I was thinking a GUID approach or something similar but I am not sure it serves the purpose. What approach can be valid with SQL Sserver? The purpose of this mechanism is to evaluate all the possible combinations of members (rows) of different sets (tables) and assign a unique name to any combination needed for later use.

Example

```
Input Tables A and B

+----+----+   +----+----+
| Table A |   | Table B |
+----+----+   +----+----+
| A1 | A2 |   | B1 | B2 |
+----+----+   +----+----+
|  1 |  2 |   | a  |  b |
|  3 |  4 |   | c  |  d |
+----+----+   +----+----+
```

Result Set Table A X B + Unique Identifier

```
+----+----+----+----+ +-----+
| A1 | A2 | B1 | B2 | | UID |
+----+----+----+----+ +-----+
|  1 |  2 | a  |  b | | 001 |
|  1 |  2 | c  |  d | | 002 |
|  3 |  4 | a  |  b | | 003 |
|  3 |  4 | c  |  d | | 004 |
+----+----+----+----+ +-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `row_number()`:

```
select
    a.a1,
    a.a2,
    b.b1,
    b.b2,
    row_number() over(order by a.a1, a.a2, b.b1, b.b2) uid
from a
cross join b
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, i was indeed looking at the row_number() function but i am afraid that if i add a row 2,5 to table A, since 2 is in the middle of 1 and 3, the row_number mechanism might return a different counting compared to the counting obtained by the unmodified table A. Maybe i am wrong and i do not grasp the row_number() mechanism so i will do some test. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a unique identifier that is consistent over time, then combine the two identifiers in the tables:

```
concat(a1, ':', b1)
```

This assumes that `a1` and `b1` are primary keys.

If you don't have primary keys, then add one.  That will facilitate what you want to do.

You can take the risk of using hashing functions.  Something like this:

```
select concat(convert(varchar(32), hashbytes('MD5', concat(a1, ':', a2), 2), ':',
              convert(varchar(32), hashbytes('MD5', concat(b1, ':', b2), 2)
             )
```

This runs the risk of collisions (hash values that are the same even though the underlying values are not the same), but that is pretty low.  It is an argument for using primary keys.

Comment: Gordon, let's say that the concat works well generating a first string, then i might use the hashbytes to convert the whole string into a single hashcode.

Comment: @Paolo . . . Yes.  But I encourage you to use primary keys instead.